Trying to draw a directed graph based on a process
I'm trying to draw a process as a directed graph, but I'm finding this an impossible task. My process only have 6 nodes, A, B, C, D, E and F. The process is like this:
B is only directly reachable from A.
C is only directly reachable from B.
D is directly reachable either from B or from C.
E is only directly reachable from D.
F is only directly reachable from E and from C.
This last step is resulting impossible to me, because it says that to reach F, I must touch both nodes E and C. If I can reach F only walking through one of them, my process is invalid.Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance.
Edit
In the graph draw by @David, for example, I can reach F either from E or from C, and this is not the idea.

Can you define "only possible"? Does it refer to an edge, or a walk? Since D is possible either from B or from C, how is E only possible from  D but not B?

E needs D, which needs C or B, and therefore B. But I can only go directly from D to E, I can't go from B to E. The graph showed below by @David exemplifies the first steps... my problem is the last one. I cannot show that F is reachable only if I walk C AND E. What he shows to reach F leaves the possibility of ignoring C or E to reach F.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here is the directed graph you seek....


Thanks for the answer. However in this graph I'm seeing that I can reach F without touching C if I walk from B to D to E to F.

Perhaps your constraints are incompatible with a simple directed graph.

Yes. That is my conclusion after thinking on this for several days. It's no possible to write this constraints in a directed graph.
